# Accessing helpers to get session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have in my application 2 different controllers that should access the same session object. Currently i'm using `:active_record_store` because i don't want to use database for fetching my users.

i'm doing something like this:

the api controller takes a user email and creates a user object (valid?, hash, and other methods)

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def login
    user = Requester.validate_email params[:email]
    if user.valid?
      session[:current_user] = user # works
      current_user = user           # dont work
      redirect_to app_root_path
    else
      redirect_to app_signup_path
    end
  end
end
```

the home controller will display some page to the user, given he is already "logged" in

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    puts "Home"

    # Everything here works fine
    puts session[:current_user].hash
    puts session[:current_user]
    puts session[:current_user].nil?

    # Nothing here works
    puts current_user.hash
    puts current_user
    puts current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

the `current_user` and `current_user=` methods are located on `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

private 
  def current_user
    session[:user]
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    session[:user] = user
  end
end
```

what am i doing wrong? why i cant access the `session[:user]` from inside the private methods ?

---

using rails 3.2.11 and sqlite3 in development and postgresql in production

---

**EDIT**

i found my problem, apparently i can't use `current_user = <some object>`, if i use the `current_user(<some object>)` then this would work.

```
def current_user(user)
  session[:user] = user
end

def current_user=(user)
  session[:user] = user
end

def current_user
  session[:user]
end
```

Comment: is session[:user] and session[:current_user] the same?

Comment: no, if they are the same i couldn't see the diference. but even if i change :user with :current_user it doesn't work

Comment: Are you using devise by any chance? There is a chance that some library that you have included is adding a function by the same name to your controller.

Comment: no, no devise at all. i'm using everything from scratch

Comment: You are on the right track. user2191327 has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

current_user = user # this set variable current_user with value = user

self.current_user = user # this call method current_user=() with arg user